# How to wait till all threads finish their work?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have the following script (don't refer to the contents):

```
import _thread

def func1(arg1, arg2):
    print("Write to CLI")

def verify_result():
    func1()


for _ in range (4):
    _thread.start_new_thread(func1, (DUT1_CLI, '0'))

verify_result()
```

I want to concurrently execute (say 4 threads) **func1()** which in my case includes a function call that can take time to execute. Then, only after the last thread finished its work I want to execute **verify_result()**.

Currently, the result I get is that all threads finish their job, but **verify_result()** is executed before all threads finish their job.

I have even tried to use the following code (of course I imported threading) under the for loop but that didn't do the work (don't refer to the arguments)

```
t = threading.Thread(target = Enable_WatchDog, args = (URL_List[x], 180, Terminal_List[x], '0'))
t.start()
t.join()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last `threading` example is close, but you have to collect the threads in a list, start them all at once, then wait for them to complete all at once.  Here's a simplified example:

```
import threading
import time

# Lock to serialize console output
output = threading.Lock()

def threadfunc(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        time.sleep(.01) # sleep to make the "work" take longer
        with output:
            print(i)

# Collect the threads
threads = []
for i in range(10,100,10):
    # Create 9 threads counting 10-19, 20-29, ... 90-99.
    thread = threading.Thread(target=threadfunc,args=(i,i+10))
    threads.append(thread)

# Start them all
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# Wait for all to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a list of threads.
You loop(each_thread) over them -

```
for each_thread in thread_pool:
    each_thread.start()
```

within the loop to start execution of the run function within each thread.

The same way, you write another loop **after** you start all threads and have

```
for each_thread in thread_pool:
    each_thread.join()
```

what join does is that it will wait for thread i to finish execution before letting i+1th thread to finish execution.

The threads would run concurrently, `join()` would just synchronize the way each thread returns its results.

In your case specifically, you can the `join()` loop and the run `verify_result()` function.

Comment: I am new to Python and especially to threading. Can you please explain a bit more what do you mean by thread pool ? How can I prepare a list of threads ?

Comment: @MosheS. By thread pool, i mean a literal collection of threads. Say you have a job that needs to be executed 5 times and preferably concurrently, you happen to create (not start execution) 2 threads for this, now each of the thread will take up a job each, 3 jobs will wait till one thread gets free to pick them up, so check the thread pool if a thread is free to do so, else wait, till there is. By list of threads, i meant a list of thread objects. You iterate over them and start the job, which is what I thought you wanted to do. In my answer thread_pool refers to such a list, not thread pool.